# How do I minimize the amount of memory needed for a fixed allocation scheme?

Tags: algorithm, memory-management

The following image visualizes the needed life span for 16 memory blocks of various sizes:

[image]

What I'm essentially looking for is given a number of ***N*** blocks of size ***size<sub>i</sub>*** and lifetime ***[begin<sub>i</sub>, end<sub>i</sub>)***, return the minimum sized total memory block needed to contain them during our total time interval and ***N*** offsets, ***offset<sub>i</sub>***, into this total memory block for the input blocks.

A trivial non optimal algorithm would be the following:

```
int offsets[N];
offsets[0] = 0;
int total_size = size[0];
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
{
    offsets[i] = offsets[i - 1] + size[i - 1];
    total_size += size[i];
}
```

Our current algorithm is to sort the blocks by size and then process them from largest to smallest, finding the first offset where the block doesn't overlap with an already "allocated" block. This is essentially a greedy algorithm, so I have a feeling that it would be possible to do better.

The algorithm only needs to be run once at the start of the application so it doesn't have to be superfast. The number of allocations is in the order of 10-50 and for our purposes the time can be discretized into around 50 fixed size units.

Comment: This is a very vague hint, but isn't the canonical way of cheating around a greedy algorithm trying out several possible solutions where you introduce randomness or some other deviation from the straightforward approach, and seeing if you get an improvement? (E.g. pairwise exchange for the TSP, etc.)

Comment: (Aside: your visualisation is a little confusing, wouldn't "memory used" over tome be better? It might or might not let you spot gaps and how they might be filled. The "allocation ID" doesn't seem very important.)

Comment: Can you elaborate? The Allocation ID basically represents distinct objects and the bar represents during which periof of the execution of the program they are active, it's very important.

Comment: Right, I realise now it's a visualisation of how your *input* is structured. So what I should have asked is if you could (in addition) make a visualisation of the *output* your greedy algorithm provides, where one axis is memory used (the block going from ***offset_i*** to ***offset_i+size***) and the other is time as in here. Any visible gaps *might* provide a hint on what to rearrange to get rid of such inefficiencies. (Or it might be a wild goose chase, I admit.)

Comment: Are the sizes of your blocks also nicely discretizable? In your figure, it looks like they are all small multiples of 265k.

Comment: For the purpose of this discussion, lets assume that the sizes are integers in a range of about 1-50

Answer (score 0):

Find the minimum start time and maximum end time from your list of ***begin*** and ***end*** time intervals.  This is the total interval, (t_min, t_max), of time you are interested in.  Next, divide the time interval into some discrete and uniform intervals.  Let the length of this interval be *u*.  This is basically the maximum resolution of your memory management (how often you can possibly free and/or claim a block of memory).

For each unit of time, determine which Allocation IDs need memory and what size they each require at that time, call it *s(t, id)*.  The sum of *s(t, id)* over all allocation IDs is a lower bound of how much total memory you require at any given time.  You can't do any better than the maximum of this function, which fails to take into account the desire to keep things allocated in the same region without moving them at each time step.

To find an optimal position for each item you could use a heuristic search.  Basically, search the state space of all possible starting addresses for each memory block  for the solution that takes up the smallest total amount of memory, which you find by simulating the progression of time from t_min to t_max.

A heuristic that might be worth trying is to prefer allocations where big chunks occupy spaces previously occupied by other big chunks, and small chunks are placed at locations with small contribution to the maximum memory usage of the strategy.  You could also prune any strategy found that is worse than the best seen so far since the maximum memory claimed by the strategy is monotonic over time.

The heuristic search method may be slow, but it sounds like you care more about optimal memory usage than runtime of the allocation algorithm.